# render dynamic data in a new route onClick - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to render the `handleCrawl()` onClick. And it has to go to another Route.
Currently my route changes but I couldn't render the `<SwaggerUI url={api.opening_crawl}/>`. I dont know woh to pass the `handleCrawl()` to another function.

This function handles the click event to show a piece of data.

```
 handleCrawl = e => {
  const { id } = e.target;
  this.setState(current => ({
    showCrawl: { [id]: !current.showCrawl[id] }
  }));
};
```

This is my render method where it maps the list of link to click and Render.

```
 render() {
  return (
      <div>
        {this.state.apis.map(api => (
      <NavLink to={`api/${api.id}`} key={api.id}
         id={api.id}
          onClick={this.handleCrawl}>{api.title}</NavLink>
          ))}
      <div>
      {this.state.apis.map(api => (
        <div
          key={api.id}
          id={api.id}>
          {this.state.showCrawl[api.id] && (  
            <SwaggerUI url={api.opening_crawl}/>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're mixing routing and state a bit here. Just create a navigation link that will change the route to `api/:id`. No need to call `handleCrawl`. Also `state.showCrawl` could be replaced by `this.props.match.params.id`. If you need to do an API request on route change you can create a `fetchData` method and call it in `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` life cycle methods.

Comment: @AWolf, im getting `Cannot read property 'params' of undefined` error. do I need to set params anywhere. Im new to react

Comment: sorry, for my late response. Could you please create a minimal [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) then I could have a look? Not sure why you don't have params in your component, it's difficult without seeing your complete code.